# Choropleth change polygon colour based on layer in R leaflet

Tags: javascript, r, dictionary, leaflet, polygon

I have a large number of polygons (>5000 to cover the UK) that even simplified cause quite a large map file. I also have a set of information about each of these polygons with a value per week over a 13 week period.

I want to plot this as a cloropleth with each week being a layer and the colour of the polygon being related to the value for that week.

So far I have been able to make it work by merging the SPDF and DF then cycling through all 13 weeks but this causes a map that takes a very long time to load and the output html file is massive. Ideally as the polygons never change, just their colour, I would want to have the colour update based on the layer that is selected.

I have the following code as a minimum example to show what I have got so far. I used a numeric value for cycle rather than a timeseries but the principle should be the same.

```
# Libraries and data load
library(tigris)
library(spdplyr)
library(leaflet)

states <- states(cb=T)

binpal <- colorBin(c("red", "yellow", "green"), -5:5, c(-5, -0.5, 0.5, 5), pretty = FALSE)


# Subset to less states for example
states_subset <- states[5:10,]

state_names <- states_subset$NAME

# Generate random measure data
set.seed(100)

df <- data.frame(cycle = 1, state_names, val =rnorm(6))

for (i in 2:5){df <- df %>% rbind(data.frame(cycle = i, state_names, val = rnorm(6)))}


# Join the data and produce the map 1 layer per cycle
state_merged <- states_subset %>% merge(df, by.x = "NAME", by.y = "state_names", duplicateGeoms = TRUE)

m <- leaflet() %>% 
    addTiles() 

for (i in 1:5){
    temp <- state_merged %>% filter(cycle == i)

    m <- m %>% 
        addPolygons(
            data = temp,
            color = ~binpal(val),
            label = ~val,
            group = as.character(i)
        )

}

m <- m %>% 
    addLayersControl(
    overlayGroups = as.character(1:5),
    options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = TRUE),
    position = "topleft"
) %>% hideGroup(as.character(1:4))

m
```

I expect the answer is in some custom JS but I don't know any to know where to start. I am not bothered about if multiple layers can be displayed at once or not.